# EJB Corba Marshalling Exception

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, websphere, ejb, marshalling

We work with a Websphere cluster with two apps in it (app1 and app2). I can call EJBs from both apps from my local spring boot out of Intellij-Idea.

When I deploy the spring boot application to the companies private openshift cloud then there is a marshalling exception in one of the two services (client side) talking to one of the websphere apps.

```
@Service
public class App1BookingsManagementService implements EjbService<DomainFacade> {

    private static final String DOMAINFACADE_EJB_NAME = "ejb/org/company/app/DomainFacade";

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App1BookingsManagementService.class);

    @Autowired
    private InitialContext initialContext;

    public List<BookingDataRow> getBookingsToday() {
        DomainFacade domainFacade = null;
        try {
            domainFacade = createEjbStub();
            BookingSelektionskriterien selektionskriterien = new BookingSelektionskriterien();
            selektionskriterien.setTerminFrom(valueOf(now()));
            selektionskriterien.setTerminUntil(valueOf(now().plusDays(1)));
            ResultList<BookingDataRow> resultList = domainFacade.sucheBookingsDataRows(selektionskriterien);
            if (resultList == null) {
                LOG.warn("Error in EJB {} from APP1 returned null. ", DOMAINFACADE_EJB_NAME);
            }
            LOG.info("Calling EJB sucheBookingsDataRows returned {} results. ", resultList.getList().size());
            return resultList.getList();
        } catch (NamingException | CreateException | RemoteException | DomainException e) {
            LOG.error("Error in calling EJB {} from APP1: {}, {}", DOMAINFACADE_EJB_NAME, e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (domainFacade != null) {
                try {
                    domainFacade.remove();
                } catch (RemoteException | RemoveException e) {
                    LOG.error("could not remove ejb {}", DOMAINFACADE_EJB_NAME, e);
                }
            }
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public DomainFacade createEjbStub() throws NamingException, RemoteException, CreateException {
        Object stub = initialContext.lookup(DOMAINFACADE_EJB_NAME);
        DomainFacadeHome facadeHome = (DomainFacadeHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(stub, DomainFacadeHome.class);
        return facadeHome.create();
    }

}
```

Here the config:

```
@Configuration
public class CorbaConfig {

    @Value("${corba-location}")
    private String corbaLocation;
    @Value("classpath:sas.client.props")
    private Resource sasClientProps;

    @Bean
    public InitialContext corbaContext() throws NamingException, IOException {
        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(PROPS.HOSTNAME_NORMALIZER, PROPS.HOSTNAME_NORMALIZER_NONE);
        env.put("com.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL", sasClientProps.getInputStream());
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, corbaLocation);
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }

    @Bean
    public MBeanServer mbeanServer() {
        MBeanServerFactoryBean factory = new MBeanServerFactoryBean();
        factory.setLocateExistingServerIfPossible(true);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

This is the error I see in openshift:

```
2021-02-04 08:14:53,714 [ERROR] P=891120:O=0:CT appname=app-ejbcall corid= c.s.n.e.s.App1BookingsManagementService: Error in calling EJB ejb/org/company/app/DomainFacade from APP1: java.rmi.MarshalException, CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f89a No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: 
    >> SERVER (id=431c9d95, host=was.company.org) TRACE START:
    >>    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Unable to read value from underlying bridge : Default data must be read first  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 89A  completed: No
    >>   at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.read_value(CDRReader.java:1644)
    >>   at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.EncoderInputStream.read_value(EncoderInputStream.java:970)
    >>   at org.company.app.Domain.ejb.facade._EJSRemoteStatelessDomainFacade_a1729579_Tie.sucheBookingenDataRows(Unknown Source)
    >>   at org.company.app.Domain.ejb.facade._EJSRemoteStatelessDomainFacade_a1729579_Tie._invoke(Unknown Source)
    >>   at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:638)
    >>   at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:508)
    >>   at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:613)
    >>   at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1584)
    >>   at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doRequestWork(Connection.java:3190)
    >>   at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:3051)
    >>   at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:64)
    >>   at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.WorkQueueElement.dispatch(WorkQueueElement.java:174)
    >>   at com.ibm.ws.giop.filter.GiopFilterChain.processMessage(GiopFilterChain.java:203)
    >>   at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.handleRequest(PooledThread.java:81)
    >>   at com.ibm.ws.giop.threadpool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:102)
    >>   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
    >> SERVER (id=431c9d95, host=was.company.org) TRACE END.
  vmcid: IBM  minor code: 89A  completed: No
```

Locally there is no problem talking to the same websphere server. One guess was the RMI stub is not the same but then it would be also a problem locally, no?

|  | App 1 | App 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Local Spring Boot run in IDE | OK | OK |
| Deployt in Openshift Cloud | OK | NOK |

Comment: The error suggests the problem is with the BookingSelektionskriterien parameter on the EJB method call, so not surprising App 1 isn't effected (if it doesn't have any methods with a similar parameter).

How certain are you that both scenarios are using the same Stub class and same version of BookingSelektionskriterien?

This appears to be an EJB written to the EJB 2.x API, but is it packaged in an EJB 2.x module or an EJB 3.x module (i.e. what version is ejb-jar.xml)?

How did you generate the Stub class?  EJBDeploy? RMIC? or createEJBStubs?

Comment: The J2EE apps are old: ejb-jar version="2.1". I think you are right, in app1 the stubbing were already there, in app2 I had to add it myself, I use rmic-maven-plugin and included just ```**/ejb/facade/*Home.class``` and ```**/ejb/facade/*Facade.class```. So no stub for BookingSelektionskriterien. But why does it work locally?

Comment: BookingSelektionskriterien does not need a stub, it isn't a remote object, it will be serialized and passed as a parameter. The fact that one environment works and not the other makes it seems like a different version of something is on the classpath of the two environments.  I'd make sure the same version of the Stub class and BookingSelektionskriterien are loaded in both environments.  If they are the same, then compare the versions of Java.  Perhaps using a different level of Java has introduced some serialization difference. Then check the versions of the ORB.

Comment: I was playing around with the dependencies: ```com.ibm.ws:ws-admin-client```, ```com.ibm.ws:orb``` and ```org.glassfish.corba:glassfish-corba-orb```. I removed the glassfish-corba-orb and it's still running locally, deployed I get ```java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject```. In both environment I'm using OpenJava 8

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I configured the build with jdk-8 but at runtime the jre was set to version 11.

So I had to find the internal configuration for the correct docker file to use java 8.